# Trying to resolve the issue 'Image' object has no attribute 'name' in Python 3.5

Tags: python, image, pdf, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to build an GUI for an application. The following code is working fine when I'm using the code as a function. It shows no errors. But when I use it in a class, this is getting crazy. It keeps throwing the error : image object has no attribute name or some other. I do not know how to solve it please can someone help me with this. Thanks

```
from PIL import Image as Img
from wand.image import Image
import uuid
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
import sys

from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename 
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk   




class TkFileDialogExample(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        button_opt = {'fill': tk.constants.BOTH, 'padx': 10, 'pady': 10}
        tk.Button(self, text='Individual files', command=self.askopenfilename).pack(**button_opt)
        self.file_opt = options = {}
        options['defaultextension'] = '.txt'
        options['filetypes'] = [('all files', '.*'), ('files', '.pdf')]
        options['initialdir'] = 'C:\\Users\\myfolder\\Pictures'
        options['parent'] = root


    def askopenfilename(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(**self.file_opt)
        filename_temp = str(filename)[1:-2]
        print(filename_temp)

        if len(filename_temp) == 0: 
            result = Label(text="Err.. : file not selected", fg="red").pack(padx=105, pady=2)
        else:

            filepdf = filename_temp[1:-1]
            filepdf = filepdf.replace('/', '\\')
            try:
                print('file name is ',filepdf)
                with Image(filename=filepdf, resolution=200) as img:
                    img.compression_quality = 99
                    #save it to tmp name
                    img.save(filename='C:\\Users\\myfolder\\Pictures\\%s.jpeg') 
            except Exception as err:
                print(err)
                return False
        result = Label(text="Done Successfully !" , fg="blue").pack(padx=105, pady=2)
        return   result


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    root = tk.Tk()
    TkFileDialogExample(root).pack()
    Label(text="Log : ", fg="blue").pack(padx=100, pady=5)
    root.mainloop()
```

This is the error I get when I run the code:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method Image.__del__ of <tkinter.Image object at 0x0000000007799F28>>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\Python3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3499, in __del__
        if self.name:
    `AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'name''
```

Comment: Is that the complete traceback? If so, what are the steps to trigger this exception? Is it when you quit after having given it a filename, or…?

Comment: `tkinter.Image` needs an `imgtype` argument and does not understand `filename` and `resolution`. I do not thing that is what you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

> You imported PIL Image as Img, you shouldnt be writing Image but Img wherever you would like to use the attribute name